# Showing Percentage in SSRS Tablix

Tags: reporting-services, sql-server-2012, expression, ssrs-2012, percentage

I am using Visual Studio 2012 and SQL Server 2012. My question is concerning how to show percentages in my SSRS Tablix based on fields I currently have.

I have a `WithinRequirements` field that I used a case statement to tell me if a particular `Business_ID` falls within the requirements or not. In this case, if a `Business_ID` with the name `Headquarters` is completed within 10 days, then it receives a 1, if not then a 0.

```
CASE WHEN AgeBusiness >= 0 AND AgeBusiness <10 AND [Name] like '%Headquarters%' THEN 1
ELSE 0
End AS WithinRequirements
```

From that, applying my filters and rest of query, I get about 601 `Business_ID` records that either result in a 0 or a 1.

Now I am trying to create a column in my tablix to show percentages for `WithinRequirements`.

Basically, I am trying to get an expression in `SSRS` for the column that says:

```
(Count of Business_ID where WithinRequirements = 
                1/Total Number of Business_ID where WithinRequirements = 1 or 0) * 100)
```

I'm not sure how to make this expression. Can anybody help me out with this? I tried:

`= Count(Fields!WithinRequirements.Value)/Sum(Fields!WithinRequirements.Value)* 100`

as my expression, but that is not working.

Any help would be appreciated and thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

`Sum(Fields!WithinRequirements.Value)/Count(Fields!WithinRequirements.Value) * 100`

Comment: I see, you have to treat `WithinRequirements` correctly, I am guessing you have missing data for it. So it will fail at `sum` or `count`, check whether you have **null** or empty in your final result before getting the final ratio

Comment: How is it not working? Also while the answer provided by @LONG will return a percentage value it won't display as a percentage on the report. To do this leave off the multiplier to return a decimal value, and then format the textbox/placeholder as a percentage

Comment: @LONG - So currently WithinRequirements, all the numbers that I'm pulling in have a 0 or a 1, so there are no NULLs or empty values.

Comment: @Paul - Currently it constantly returns a 0% or a NaN. I already formatted the textbox to a percentage.

Comment: Nan (Not a Number) means you've got 0/0 happening. What grouping do you have on the report?